# Methods of solving an initial-value problem for a separable first-order ODE

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In *Schaum's outline of Differential Equations* it is said that the initial-value problem of $A(x) d x+B(y) d y=0 $; $y\left(x_{0}\right)=y_{0}$ can be solved either $(1)$ integrating and applying the initial condition to evaluate $c$ or by using $(2)$:

$$
\int A(x) d x+\int B(y) d y=c; \quad y\left(x_{0}\right)=y_{0} \tag{1}
$$

$$
\int_{x_{0}}^{x} A(x) d x+\int_{y_{0}}^{y} B(y) d y=0 \tag{2}
$$

It is also said that this second method *may not determine the solution of the initial-value problem uniquely; thal is, it may have many solutions, of which only one will satisfy the initial-value problem.*

As I see it, both methods are equivalent: if $\widetilde A(x)$ and $\widetilde B(y)$ are the primitive functions of $A(x)$ and $B(y)$, then

$$(1) \rightarrow \widetilde A(x) + \widetilde B(y) =c \rightarrow c= \widetilde A(x_0) + \widetilde B(y_0)\rightarrow \\\widetilde A(x)- \widetilde A(x_0) + \widetilde B(y)- \widetilde B(y_0)=0$$

Which is the same result we get from $(2)$:

$$(2) \rightarrow \widetilde A(x)- \widetilde A(x_0) + \widetilde B(y)- \widetilde B(y_0)=0$$

Why does then the book say that the second method may *may not determine the solution of the initial-value problem uniquely*?

Answer (score 1):

This is true for both methods, $\tilde B$ need not be a monotonous function, there might be multiple points in its pre-images of the value $c-\tilde A(x)$.

Why that was only attached to the second variant can only be guessed, perhaps there  was a stylistic influence, a tendency towards a narrower narrative flow...